# Convert UTC string to local time string moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've a utc time string lets say 05:01 I want to convert this into localtime string.
Something like this 08:33.

I've tried this but its giving blank output.

```
var str = "05:03";
var d = moment(str, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm').local();
```

I want to make it work using momemt js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trying to call `.format().local()` you were calling `.local()` on a string type which won't work. If you put the `.local()` before the `.format()` it'll convert it to local time and then convert it to a string. I've also used the moment.utc method to ensure that the string is parsed in the utc timezone instead of your local timezone.

```
var str = "05:03";
var d = moment.utc(str, 'HH:mm').local().format('HH:mm');
```

Hope this helps.